# how to connect the to a telegram bot

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

i want to connect ooga booga web ui(running vicuna or Pygmalion AI) running on google collab to a telegram bot to make a personal ai assistant who could talk to me ,start up a conversation with me and helps to keep of activities using google calander  and remember conversations  using a db like hyper db

i have tried nothing as im new to bot making

Comment: "I have tried nothing" means that your question is not for StackOverflow. Please see [tour] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

For this occasion, you could use python to run a telegram bot, and then add features you want to it.

This is the minimum code needed to run a telegram bot. I suggest not to run this in Colab, but in a VM

```
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, ContextTypes, CommandHandler

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',level=logging.INFO)


async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,text="I'm a bot.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token('YOURTOKEN').build()
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    application.add_handler(start_handler)
    application.run_polling()
```

After the bot is set up, you may add features to it... this is python. Possibilities are endless.

If you message me, I could help more.

Comment: thank you for the help i would also like to run it in a vm but my pc is not up to the task  it only has 4gb vram  so  and im planing to make it to run stable diffusion and vicuuna side by side

Comment: To achieve these features you would need more resources :)

well, and more knowledge than i have. the best thing i've ever done in a python bot was to use `bardapi` (really useful by the way)

`bardapi.core.Bard().get_answer("hello")`